# Jenkins how to skip a goal which is present in project pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins, pom.xml

Is there any way to skip a goal in `maven-antrun-plugin` which is present in **pom.xml** of a project from **jenkins**?
I am running jenkins job for one of my project which is getting source code from SVN (I can't change the pom.xml content which is coming from SVN).
Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an alternative pom to your Jenkins job.
This pom being a copy of original one but without antrun plugin.

Comment: I can't modify existing code base.. (adding/updating)

Comment: Yes. But you can probably copy and edit the pom locally, on the Jenkins host.

Comment: I am looking for a solution without manual interaction, which should be taken care by Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I know you cannot change the code, but i want to give you my opinion as well.

One of the best approach for me can be simply to add a profile to the pom, then use this profile to skip or to run specified goals...

So when you will run the pom (with or without the profile) you will be able to switch easily from one configuration to the other...

I don't think you will fine a clean solution to avoid that goal, i meant a standard one...

So if you are thinking something dirty as workaround, remember that in the job configuration you can always put something between the SVN checkout and the Maven build, something like an ant script, or a groovie script or simply a shell, this logic should temporally delete the part of the pom you don't want to run, then you can avoid the commit of this change, or just update the pom.xml at the original version before commit it...

This is what i would do as dirty solution...